# Remove axis markings on EPPlus scatter chart

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm generating a chart using EPPlus for Excel.
What I want to be able to do is to remove the circled horizontal bars from the graph axes.
Does anyone know how to do this?
My current code is as below

```
        var p = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(fileName));
        var openSheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

        var scatterChart = openSheet.Drawings.AddChart("Worm Calc", eChartType.XYScatter);
        scatterChart.Series.Add(openSheet.Cells["E3:E103"], openSheet.Cells["F3:F103"]);

        scatterChart.Legend.Remove();

        scatterChart.XAxis.LogBase = 10;
        scatterChart.YAxis.LogBase = 10;
        scatterChart.XAxis.RemoveGridlines(true, true); //does not help
        scatterChart.XAxis.RemoveGridlines(); //does not help
        scatterChart.Title.Text = "Worm Calc";
        scatterChart.SetPosition(2, 0, 7, 0);
        scatterChart.SetSize(350, 350);
        p.SaveAs(new FileInfo(fileName));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `RemoveGridLines()` will not do it as it was designed to remove the horizontal and vertical lines of the chart (I know, I wrote it :) ).

You are looking to remove the Tick Marks.  You only circled some of them on each axis but I assume you actually want to remove ALL of them.  To do that:

```
scatterChart.XAxis.MajorTickMark = eAxisTickMark.None;
scatterChart.XAxis.MinorTickMark = eAxisTickMark.None;
scatterChart.YAxis.MajorTickMark = eAxisTickMark.None;
scatterChart.YAxis.MinorTickMark = eAxisTickMark.None;
```

If you are looking to remove ONLY those that are circled, AFAIK, excel (nothing to do with EPPlus) cannot do that.  It is all or nothing.

Comment: Wow, I was just reading your post about RemoveGridlines() from three years ago, and you're still responding three years afterwards! Awesome